# Display lagging (printing from top to bottom )

Tags: display, screen

Hello today when I booted my Ubuntu 20.04 it was slow and the screen from the login menu was lagging and printing slowly from top to bottom. This is happening after login too, I see every window I open being printed top to bottom, also when I scroll. This has never happened before, and I didn't do anything it was like this when I booted. I have a dual boot with windows 10 if that helps. I'm sorry if this is a known issue but i couldn't find any info online..

EDIT: I am indeed using AMD Radeon R9 280X from ASUS, (a pretty old GPU) but it was working fine for months.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I just uninstalled the AMD driver using `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and that probably reverted back to the old "basic" driver idk which one it is but its working ok now. I will probably try and install amdgpu when a new version is released.